# perform reseed the ID column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a database table called Deposit and i want to reseed the value of the ID column of the table.

[image]

I use the following code:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Deposit, RESEED, 0)
```

But the error shows that DBCC is not supported by sql server compact edition Is there any other way to do this in compact edition other than DBCC?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to keep the data in the table?

Comment: I am not sure if this is available on `sql-server-ce`, try `Truncate Table Deposit`. If supported it will delete all the data and reseed to ID to original value.

Comment: truncate is also not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are workarounds.
Check this out...

It looks like programmatically you can Alter Column - not interactively.
Or you can drop and recreate if you don't need the data.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/871f38d9-8c77-4050-b5dd-ebab1b88b330/sql-server-compact-reseed-identity-column